# Mi maestro detalle no funciona ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-3, coffeescript

Hola mire hize un ejemplo lo que deberia hacer, las fotos esta en este vinculo https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8tEXZ0-P1YHSkE1TFRid0ZhWjA?usp=sharing pero no funciona me recarga la pagina cada vez que le doy agregar otro mas o si voy a eliminar siempre me recarga la pagina gracias por la atención prestada.

Un ejemplo de la base de datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

snack.rb

```
class Snack < ApplicationRecord
   self.table_name = 'snacks'
   belongs_to :planta
   belongs_to :centro_costo
   belongs_to :productonack

   has_many :detallenacks, :dependent => :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :detallenacks, allow_destroy: true

   def detallenacks_for_form
     collection = detallenacks.where(snack_id: id)
     collection.any? ? collection : detallenacks.build
   end

end
```

productonack.rb

```
class Productonack < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'productonacks'
  belongs_to :planta
  belongs_to :negocionac
  belongs_to :detallenack, optional: true
end
```

detallenack.rb

```
class Detallenack < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'detallenacks' 
  belongs_to :snack
  belongs_to :productonack
end
```

snacks_controller.rb

```
class SnacksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_snack, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /snacks
  # GET /snacks.json
  def index
    @snacks = Snack.all
  end

  # GET /snacks/1
  # GET /snacks/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /snacks/new
  def new
    @snack = Snack.new
    @snack.detallenacks.build
  end

  # GET /snacks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /snacks
  # POST /snacks.json
  def create
    @snack = Snack.new(snack_params)

    respond_to do |format|
     if @snack.save
       format.html { redirect_to @snack, notice: 'Snack was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @snack }
     else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @snack.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
   end
  end

 # PATCH/PUT /snacks/1
 # PATCH/PUT /snacks/1.json
 def update
    respond_to do |format|
     if @snack.update(snack_params)
       format.html { redirect_to @snack, notice: 'Snack was successfully updated.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @snack }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @snack.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
 end

 # DELETE /snacks/1
 # DELETE /snacks/1.json
 def destroy
   @snack.destroy
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to snacks_url, notice: 'Snack was successfully destroyed.' }
       format.json { head :no_content }
     end
 end

 private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_snack
    @snack = Snack.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def snack_params
    params.require(:snack).permit(:hora_pedido, :fecha_pedido,
      :hora_inicio, :hora_final, :fecha_entrega, :observacion,
      :planta_id, :centro_costo_id, :ubicacion, :nombre,
      :hora_entrega, :snackfullnombre, :snackfullname, :productonack_id,
        detallenacks_attributes: [:id,:productonack_id, :cantidad, :snack_id, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

snacks.coffee

```
jQuery ->
$(document).on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
  $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()

$(document).on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
```

snacks_helper.rb

```
module SnacksHelper
   def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
      new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
      id = new_object.object_id
      fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |detallenacks_for_form|
         render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: detallenacks_for_form)
       end
     link_to(name, '', class: "add_fields", data: { id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
   end


 end
```

_form.html.erb

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@snack) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>
  otros campos
  este partial redirecciona 
  <div class="row">
   <div class=" col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-md-2"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-10  col-sm-10  col-md-8 ">
     <hr>
     <div class="row compact wello">
       <%= f.fields_for :detallenacks do |detallenacks_for_form| %>
       <%= render 'det_fields',  f: detallenacks_for_form %>
       <% end %>
       <%= link_to_add_fields '<i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down fa-3x color-red"  
     aria-hidden="true"></i>'.html_safe,  f, :detallenacks %>
     </div>
     <hr> 
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2  col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div>
   </div>
<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

_det_fields.html.erb

```
 <fieldset>
   <div class="row compact">
     <div class="col-md-1"></div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
        <strong>producto</strong>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
        <strong>Cantidad  </strong>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-5">

     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row compact">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.association :productonack, label: false, class: "form-control", 
      prompt:"Seleccione el insumo" %>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
     <%= f.input :cantidad, label: false, class: "form-control" ,
     placeholder:"La cantidad " %>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-5">

  </div>


   <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
   <%= link_to "Eliminar", '#', class: "remove_fields btn btn-danger" %>
</div>
```

LOG

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CUANDO LE DOY CLIC
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Primero se debería revisar bien las relaciones que tienes hechas, según tu ER, el tipo de relación que tienes es de mucho a muchos.

Ya que la tabla detalle tiene propiedades propias es mejor utilizar through para poder accesar a ellas.

también habría que revisar la migración.

snack.rb

```
class Snack < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :detallenacks, :dependent => :destroy, through: :detallesnack
end
```

Detalle snack.rb

```
class Detallenack < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :snack
  belongs_to :productonack
end
```

product snack.rb

```
class Productonack < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :snack, through: :detallesnack
end
```

Comment: gracias @sarevalo pero no me dio.